# Sampling from a given pdf

Tags: probability-distributions, sampling, bessel-functions, inverse-function

I have the following pdf:
$$ f(x) = C x^d I_0\left(b \sqrt{- \log\left(\frac{x}{A}\right)}\right)$$
for $0 < x \leq A$, $C$ is a normalizing constant, $b$, $d$ are constants, and $I_0$ is the modified Bessel function of first kind of order $0$.

I know that in order to sample from $f$, I can use:

- Inverse CDF method
- Acceptance rejection technique

The problem with the first is that I was enable to compute the CDF, and thus not able to inverse it. Regarding the second, I know that I have to find a pdf $g$ such that the ratio of pdfs is upper bounded by some constant. The problem is that, I'm not familiar with the modified Bessel function of first kind, so I was hoping if you could help me find $g$ or if you know other sampling techniques that may be helpful in this case.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this real-life sampling for specific given constants (in which case you can use numerical methods) or are you trying to find a general 'formula' for sampling?

Comment: The constants depend on the problem but they are given. What kind of numerical methods are you referring to?

Comment: Go ahead and give me the constants (or any reasonable constants) and I'll show you what I mean, but I meant using Mathematica or any other tool/technique to numerically integrate your pdf.

Comment: I know how to integrate this pdf in Mathematica, the problem is if you plan on computing the CDF numerically using Mathematica, you won't get an analytical expression.

Comment: OK, that's why I asked if you were looking for a general formula.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (see my latest question whose +50 Bounty I just posted) ... first sample $u=U[0,1]$ (think of it as your CDF F(x) target value) then take a random value of $x$ from 0 to A, to wit $x_1=AU[0,1]$ now compute $f(x_1)$ and then multiply it by sufficiently small $\Delta x$ ... do this repeatedly computing $z_j = \sum_{i=1}^{j}f(x_i)\Delta x$ take as your sample the $x_j$ where $z_j > u$